# get id of parent of button java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="mainDiv">     
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <div style="padding-top: 25px">
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeFunction()" >Delete</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>  




function removeFunction(){
    var parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
    console.log(parent_id);
    alert(parent_id);
    $('#'+parent_id).remove();
}
```

by the upper code i want to get id of div in which button is present and delete it but in console log and in debugger the value i get is 'undefined'

Comment: correction .... ID of mainDiv

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to have so many `.parent()` calls (or any other DOM traversal) chained together. What if your HTML changes? You have to do a lot of figuring out. It's better to use `.closest()` or similar to get to a known ancestor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `this` (it was missing in your code) and you need to use that in your `removeFunction` function instead of `this`:

```js
function removeFunction(elem) {
  var parent_id = $(elem).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
  console.log(parent_id);
  alert(parent_id);
  $('#' + parent_id).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div style="padding-top: 25px">
      <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="removeFunction(this)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cannot use this .closest because ids are being dynamically generated so they will change in each div